# How run Polymer code example?

Tags: polymer

I have downloaded this example : [PolymerElements/app-layout-templates](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates)
..and I can't make it work (whereas I was able to access this one : [PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/releases/tag/v1.1.1))

I ran the following lines in the terminal :

```
bower init

bower -save polymer

bower bower install –save Polymer/polymer-elements Polymer/polymer-ui-elements

bower update
```

...and then accessed the folder via a python server.

Do you have some tips to make it work ?

Comment: If you want to use PolymerElements/app-layout-templates that's what you need to install in bower `bower install --save PolymerElements/app-layout-templates`. It will download all the required dependencies for app-layout-templates to work.

Comment: I only need to run this line ? I did in the app-layout-templates repertory but it didn't work, I got this error : `"NetworkError: 404 File not found - http://localhost:8080/Documents/Code/Polymer/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"`

Comment: When you run bower install, did all the dependencies got downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try out `PolymerElements/app-layout-templates` then that's what you need to install on bower. Bower will download all the required dependencies for app-layout-templates to work.

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/app-layout-templates
```

After this you can start python server on folders `app-layout-template`, `app-layout-template/nav-view` etc to see how it works.

Also the repositories `Polymer/polymer-elements, Polymer/polymer-ui-elements` are invalid. The polymer elements are available in github repository `https://github.com/PolymerElements`. So to download polymer elements try something like below

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-elements
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements
bower install --save PolymerElements/neon-elements
bower install --save PolymerElements/platinum-elements
```

Comment: Do i need to download something else than the app-layout-templates from github ? I mean : Do the app-layout-templates folder needs to be included in another specific folder ? 

I have tried your solution : I got this warning : `Unable to find a suitable version for platform, please choose one:
    1) platform#^0.3.0 which resolved to 0.3.6 and is required by core-component-page#0.3.6, polymer#0.3.6
    2) platform#^0.4.0 which resolved to 0.4.2 and is required by core-component-page#0.4.2, polymer#0.4.2
 `

Comment: ...and then when I tried to view it : `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2015 12:14:06] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2015 12:14:06] "GET /webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: Please remove bower_components folder and then try running the install again. The core-* are from old version of polymer. If you are running this properly, you should not see those error message. Once the bower install is complete, you should see folders like `bower_components/webcomponents`, `bower_components/app-layout-templates`